# What is the role of と after a noun when it doesn't appear to count or list anything?

Tags: particle-と

The sentence I'm trying to understand is this one:

> いっすんぼうしは おじいさんと おばあさん よび おひめさま**と** けっこんして しあわせに くらしました

I don't understand the meaning of the second と (in bold).

To me all the sentence is like

> Issunboushi invited grandpa and grandma **and by** marrying the princess (they) lived happy

So, there is one pre-masu form with よび (as time sequence) and て-link form with けっこんして (as mean).

If this is right, I don't understand what the second と is doing. と would be "and" and the て-linkage will be "by" in bold in my sentence above?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you leave out a を before よび?

Comment: No. I wrote it exactly as it appears on the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This と means "with".

In the case of the verb けっこんする it is used to mark the person you are marrying.

Xとけっこんする = "I will marry **with** X" = "I will marry X.

You'll see と meaning "with" in quite a few places. Some other examples would be:

Xと会う = meet with X.

AとBを比べる = compare B with A.

Your understanding of the rest of the sentence looks good.